# Assigning static instances to non-static ones in Flyweight pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, static, flyweight-pattern

I was going through the Flyweight sample code at http://www.oodesign.com/flyweight-pattern-wargame-example-java-sourcecode.html and wondering how it really works when we assign a static instance (`SOLDIER` as in the above site) to a non-static soldier instance in `SoldierClient` do we really reduce the object size since each `SoldierClient` will somehow hold a copy of `SOLDIER` instance in each `SoldierClient` object we create?

EDIT:

In the method `moveSoldier()` 
it says

> // delete soldier representation from previous location
>   // then render soldier representation in new location

How come this doesn't affect all the objects created in class `WarGame`

```
package flyweight;

public class SoldierImp implements Soldier {

    /**
     * Intrinsic State maintained by flyweight implementation
     * Solider Shape ( graphical represetation)
     * how to display the soldier is up to the flyweight implementation
     */
    private Object soldierGraphicalRepresentation;

    /**
     * Note that this method accepts soldier location 
     * Soldier Location is Extrinsic and no reference to previous location 
     * or new location is maintained inside the flyweight implementation
     */
    public void moveSoldier(int previousLocationX, int previousLocationY,
            int newLocationX, int newLocationY) {

        // delete soldier representation from previous location 
        // then render soldier representation in new location   
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `SoldierClient` doesn't hold a *copy* of `SOLDIER`, it holds a *reference* to `SOLDIER`, and *every* `SoldierClient` holds a reference to the *same* `SOLDIER`.

*Answering the edit*

Each soldier's location is held in `SoldierClient` instances (`currentLocationX` and `currentLocationY` properties). The code comments for those properties spell it out as well: "this state is maintained by the client" (i.e., "this state is not maintained in the `SoldierImp` instance").

Everything is in `moveSoldier`'s parameters: there's no `SoldierImp` instance state. Think of it like a static utility method. Coordinates are provided by the `SoldierClient` instance; they're never stored by the `SoldierImp`--just used.

Comment: +1, but my confusion here is, if we change a property of the reference, it should also reflect in the static counterpart, but in this case it doesn't?

Comment: @coder9 The code you link to never changes a property of the reference; in fact the reference *has* no properties.

Comment: @coder9 Moved response comments into my answer (which you should accept :p

Comment: @coder9 Another way to figure it out is to just step through the code in a debugger a couple of times; sometimes it just takes seeing it "in action" before it ends up making sense :)

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation mentions:

> The solution is to keep the common state of soldiers in a shared
>   object

Really every SolderClient has a reference to SOLDIER not a copy. In every SolderClient the variable **Soldier soldier** is referencig just to one object ant it is the same for all clients.

Since Flyweight pattern uses a Singleton pattern maybe you can check it first:

http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

Each SoldierClient instance has a *reference* to a Soldier object. In this case they all point to the same instance. You'll notice that for each call to SoldierFactory, the same Soldier object is returned -- there is only one call Soldier's constructor.

See also [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)